# How to obtain debug information (symbols) for gcc OpenMP library?

Tags: linux, gcc, openmp

I have a GCC OpenMp library (libgomp.so) that doesn't contain any symbol, and I need to either install/compile a new library with symbols or obtain debug information for the library. I found something (lib64gomp1-dbg) in the gcc-5 package, but I'm not sure if this is what I want and I don't know how to install it either (I've tried `sudo apt-get lib64gompl-dbg`, but it didn't work, it threw the error: `E: Invalid operation lib64gompl-dbg`). So how can I get debug symbols for the library? I'm fresh new to Linux, can somebody give me a hint on how to do that? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I think you need `apt-get install`, not just `apt-get`.

Comment: I think the above comment solves your problem. Also please ask [\[ mcve \]](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)s here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

```
sudo apt install lib64gompl-dbg
```

(Note the inclusion of the word **install**.)